# Retrieve updated JS Heap memory size

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, memory, profiling

I am working on a web application that records user's screen. It works well for a screencast of less than 20 min(an est.). But chrome crashes after the mentioned time.

I want to know is it possible to get the updated heap size consumed by my application. My application works only in chrome.

I tried the code:

```
window.performance.memory
```

It give me the below result everytime:

```
MemoryInfo {
 jsHeapSizeLimit: 793000000, 
 usedJSHeapSize: 10000000,
 totalJSHeapSize: 31200000
}
```

usedJsHeapSize is the total amount of memory being used by JS objects including V8 internal objects

totalJsHeapSize is current size of the JS heap including free space not occupied by any JS objects. This means that usedJsHeapSize can not be greater than totalJsHeapSize.

Note that it is not necessarily that there has ever been totalJsHeapSize of alive JS objects.

I starts recording, the size of usedJSHeapSize must be updating in heap.
How can I get the updated usedJSHeapSize in javascript or jquery?

```
window.performance.memory
```

The above code gives the same results again and again. Let me demonstrate it below:

```
<script>
console.log("JS Heap size: " + window.performance.memory.jsHeapSizeLimit);
console.log("usedJSHeapSize: " + window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize);

var x = [];
for(var i=0; i<12345678; i++) {
    x.push(i);
}


console.log("after some calculations usedJSHeapSize: " + window.performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize);
</script>
```

**Result:**

```
JS Heap size: 1620000000
usedJSHeapSize: 10000000
after some calculations usedJSHeapSize: 10000000
```

Comment: how much memory can my application consume of heap memory in javascript. Is there any calculations that It can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't allow us to get the updated heap size. It returns same values again and again.

Comment: you have to set chrome options and add --enable-precise-memory-info to them